# flutter: red screen caused by future builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, future, builder

My flutter-firebase app starts with checking a user's state. If the user is a pro, `mypagepro` screen will show up, else `mypage` will show up. Here is my code for that.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('crews')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data['isPro'] == true) {
          return MyPagePro();
        } else {
          return MyPage();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Problem is that it takes so long to check the user's state that a red screen shows up before finally showing `mypage` or `mypagepro` screen.

[image]

I want to show `mypage` or `mypagepro` screen without showing any red screen like this. How can I avoid this red screen while checking a user's state?

Comment: Do not *create* your future in the call to FutureBuilder, which will re-execute the fetch on every call to the widget's build().  Instead, create the future in your initState, and reference it in FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `snapshot` has data.

Try this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('crews')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data['isPro'] == true) {
          return MyPagePro();
        } else {
          return MyPage();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access an attribute of the data that hasn't been received yet. Try using the following code.

```
    @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('crews')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data["isPro"]) {
          return myPagePro();
        } else {
          return MyPage();
        }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this will cause problem if `isPro` is false. The logic will not return widget.

Comment: Good catch @YoBo. let me fix it

Comment: I fixed it in my post, we posted at the same time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Need Validation Use
>
> snapshot.hasData ?  myPagePro() : MyPage()

```
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('crews')
              .doc(user.uid)
              .get(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) =>
            snapshot.hasData ?  myPagePro() : MyPage()
          );
        }
      }
    }
```